# How is the best way to map UsbConfiguration object in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, usbserial

Hello actually I'm developing an app with the use of USB, I need return the UsbConfiguration from this map structure but the compiler error is:

```
Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly
```

This is the call from the method:

```
   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private fun getConfiguration(index:Int?):
        Map<String, Any> {
    val device = usbDevice
    val configuration: UsbConfiguration = device!!.getConfiguration(index!!)
    val map = configuration.toMap() + ("index" to index)
    return map
}
```

And this is the part with the problem specific in getInterface(it).toMap():

```
fun UsbConfiguration.toMap() = mapOf(
    "id" to id,
    "interfaces" to List(interfaceCount) {
        getInterface(it).toMap() }
)
```

The code from library to the method getInterface(int index)

```
 @NonNull
public UsbInterface getInterface(int index) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Comment: What the declaration of getInterface? I guess you returning UsbConfiguration

Comment: getInterface is a method from library the library class is UsbConfiguration.class and this is the code  @NonNull
    public UsbInterface getInterface(int index) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }